# Swift: enum depended from another enum

Tags: types, enums, swift

I'm making a simple game to know new language better, I made enum that describes levels of the game. I want to make another enum that will describe enemies on each level.(Levels have different enemies). So, I want to archive something like this:

```
enum GameLevel : Int {

    case Forest = 0, Swamp, Castle
    ...
}

enum Enemies : Int {

   // if .Forest than
   case Stump = 0, Frog // Forest Enemies

   //esle if ...
   case Zombie = 0, Witch // Swamp Enemies
   case Knight = 0, Archer // Castle Enemies 


   //var ... some predefined properties that all enemies have but each enemy have it's own values  
}
```

Enemies enum has wrong syntax, but I'm looking for a way to make things like this. What would the best solution to archive this?

Comment: Hint: you can define functions inside an `enum`

Comment: @pNre I know, but I don't understand how that could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that returns all the enemies in a given level, something like this:

```
enum GameLevel : Int {
    case Forest, Swamp, Castle
}

enum Enemies : Int {

    case Stump
    case Frog
    case Zombie
    case Witch
    case Knight
    case Archer

    static func enemiesInLevel(level: GameLevel) -> [Enemies] {
        switch level {
        case .Forest:
            return [Stump, Frog]
        case .Castle:
            return [Knight, Archer]
        default:
            return []
        }
    }

}

// this is how you can call it
let forestEnemies = Enemies.enemiesInLevel(.Forest)
let castleEnemies = Enemies.enemiesInLevel(.Castle)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an instance method to GameLevel to list all the enemies related to a specific element of GameLevel.

```
enum GameLevel : Int {
    case Forest = 0, Swamp, Castle
    func enemies() -> Array<Enemy> {
        switch self {
        case .Forest: return [.Stump, .Frog]
        case .Swamp: return [.Zombie, .Witch]
        case .Castle: return [.Knight, .Archer]
    }
}

enum Enemy : Int {
    case Stump = 0, Frog, Zombie, Witch, Knight, Archer
}

let forestLevel = GameLevel.Forest
forestLevel.enemies()
```

Finally please note that Apple suggests to use singular names for enums (e.g. "Enemy" instead of "Enemies")

> Each enumeration definition defines a brand new type. Like other types in Swift, their names (such as CompassPoint and Planet) should start with a capital letter. Give enumeration types singular rather than plural names, so that they read as self-evident:
>
> ```
> var directionToHead = CompassPoint.West”
> ```
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itunes.apple.com/it/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?l=en&mt=11